# ng-if (Angularjs) comparison between two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, wordpress

I move from one controller several formations, and I want to use the "ng if" to compare the id, but it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
    var postsApi = 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=4&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';


  $http.jsonp( postsApi ).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.posts = data;

      console.log( data );
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log( 'Post load error.' );
    });

  var newsApi = 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=news&filter[posts_per_page]=4&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

    // This should go in a service so we can reuse it
  $http.jsonp(newsApi).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.news = data;

        console.log(data);
    });

  var jworldApi = 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=world&filter[posts_per_page]=4&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

    // This should go in a service so we can reuse it
    $http.jsonp(jworldApi).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.jworld = data;

        console.log(data);
    });
```

In the view:

```
    <div class="highlight-topright">


                    <ion-item class="main_post" ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="$index == 0" href="#/kikarnews/posts/{{post.ID}}">

                        <div class="wrapper">

                            <img class="full-image" src="{{ post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url }}" />

                            <h3 class="cat_name_main"> {{post.terms.category[0].name}}</h3>

                            </div>

                            <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>




</ion-item>

            <ion-item ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="$index != 0"     href="#/mysite/posts/{{post.ID}}">

                 <div class="row main_home">


                     <div class="col col-50 main_img_home">
                         <img class="full-image" src="{{ post.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url }}">
                     </div>


                     <div class="col col-50 main_title_home">
                         <h5>{{ post.date }}</h5>


                         <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>



                         </div>

                     </div>



</ion-item>
</div>

        <!---news-->

        <div class="news_mideel_home">

            <h2>news</h2>

            <ion-item ng-repeat="newsi in news" **ng-if="newsi.ID != post.ID**" href="#/mysite/posts/{{newsi.ID}}">

                <div class="row main_home">


                    <div class="col col-50 main_img_home">
                        <img class="full-image" src="{{ newsi.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url }}">
                    </div>


                    <div class="col col-50 main_title_home">
                        <h5>{{ newsi.date }}</h5>


                        <h2 ng-bind-html="newsi.title"></h2>



                    </div>

                </div>

            </ion-item>


        </div>



        <div class="jworld">

           <h2>jworld</h2>

            <div ng-repeat="jworldi in jworld">

                <ion-item ng-if="jworldi.ID == 5358"      href="#/mysite/posts/{{jworldi.ID}}">

                    <div class="row main_home">


                        <div class="col col-50 main_img_home">
                            <img class="full-image" src="{{jworldi.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url }}">
                        </div>


                        <div class="col col-50 main_title_home">
                            <h5>{{ jworldi.date }}</h5>


                            <h2 ng-bind-html="jworldi.title"></h2>



                        </div>

                    </div>

                </ion-item>


        </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Try to create a plunker / fiddle rather than making your question big.

Comment: what is output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are having problem with the below line in the news div

**ng-if="newsi.ID != post.ID** ITs working as expected because the post scope is ended in the first div tag. So in the news_mideel_home the post is empty. But you can add it by adding a new div tag like below around the i

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<ion-tem ng-repeat="newsi in news" **ng-if="newsi.ID != post.ID**" href="#/mysite/posts/{{newsi.ID}}">>
------
</ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works only if == ng but not in -! =. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you paste your both div tag and the if condition ?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="post in posts"> <ion-item ng-repeat="jworldi in jworld" ng-if="post.ID != jworldi.ID" href="#/kikarnews/posts/{{jworldi.ID}}">

Comment: It doesn't work mean its not showing up? mean it could be its always equal?

Comment: I have three items a the top of the page. Below I show more items a, but I do not want Fawcett appeared up will also be down. So I compare between the id, to make sure he was not the same.

Comment: Can you please tell me whether you requirement is something like
you have array1 = [1,2,3,4]; and array2 = [1,4,5,6]. Now you need only the contents array2 which are not present in array1 that is  5 and 6 to be displayed ?